# Use Sequelize to create a dynamic where clause based on number of items in the request body?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

Have found similar answers through the search, but I can quite crack this one. I'm using Node, Express, and Sequelize. I have a working query (included below) but I would like to modify it to support a dynamic number playlistThemes, depending on the number of themes a user selects in the client, instead of always using the four as I've done below.

I'll need to loop over the playlistThemes object (or req.body.selectedThemes) and dynamically generate similar [Op.gt] queries for each theme. I'll then need to add those to my where clause, though I could probably break it out into steps?

I'm not sure, any ideas?

```
builder.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  let playlistThemes = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(req.body.selectedThemes));
  customPlaylist = await db.songs.findAll({
    where: {
      [Op.and]: [
        { intensity: { [Op.between]: [req.body.intensity[0], req.body.intensity[1]] } }, 
        { dissonance: { [Op.between]: [req.body.dissonance[0], req.body.dissonance[1]] } },
        { peculiarity: { [Op.between]: [req.body.peculiarity[0], req.body.peculiarity[1]] } },
        // Want a dynamic number of the items below (min of 1 theme, max of 5)
        { [playlistThemes[0].name]: { [Op.gt]: [playlistThemes[0].weight] } }, 
        { [playlistThemes[1].name]: { [Op.gt]: [playlistThemes[1].weight] } }, 
        { [playlistThemes[2].name]: { [Op.gt]: [playlistThemes[2].weight] } }, 
        { [playlistThemes[3].name]: { [Op.gt]: [playlistThemes[3].weight] } }, 
    ]}
  });
  return res.send(customPlaylist);
  
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to solve this you need convert `playlistThemes` in an array of objects (or dictionary) with the flowing format:
`{ [playlistThemes[i].name]: { [Op.gt]: playlistThemes[i].weight] } }`

To solve this you can use the [array map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). For each element of the list you create an object with the desired format.

The first step is to do the mapping:

```
const themes = playlistThemes.map((theme) => {
  return { [theme.name]: { [Op.gt]: [theme.weight] } }
})
```

The second step is to add each element in the new array to the search. We can copy each element of the new array using `...themes`. This is useful to [merge arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items).

The final code is the following:

```
  builder.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  let playlistThemes = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(req.body.selectedThemes));

  const themes = playlistThemes.map((theme) => {
    return { [theme.name]: { [Op.gt]: [theme.weight] } }
  })

  customPlaylist = await db.songs.findAll({
    where: {
      [Op.and]: [
        { intensity: { [Op.between]: [req.body.intensity[0], req.body.intensity[1]] } }, 
        { dissonance: { [Op.between]: [req.body.dissonance[0], req.body.dissonance[1]] } },
        { peculiarity: { [Op.between]: [req.body.peculiarity[0], req.body.peculiarity[1]] } },
        ...themes
        ]}
      });
    return res.send(customPlaylist);
   });
```